# Identify this studio's logo or trademark

Tags: production

During the opening credits of a recent (circa 2019) movie², one of the studios in the queue¹ used a logo/trademark that reminded me of a Ishihara plate. [Ishihara plates](https://www.color-blindness.com/ishiharas-test-for-colour-deficiency-38-plates-edition/) (aka *pseudoisochromatic plates*) are commonly used to test for varying degrees of colour blindness.

[image]

Now, I'm colour blind myself and I have no idea what this logo/trademark is intended to represent. AFAIK, it could be a portion of the previous studio blurb, a new studio or the next one in the queue. In fact, my eyes cannot determine any underlying message due to my own colour vision deficiency.

Is there a message hidden in there and what studio is using this to represent themselves?

---

¹ <sub>Related: [How does this studio hierarchy work](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46166)</sub>

² <sub>The movie was *Rocketman*.</sub>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I see MARV . It's Marv films! 
[Rocketman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketman_(film))

Comment: That has to be it. Thanks for this! You have no idea how frustrating colour blindness can be. :)

Comment: Ive never seen a colour blindness plate used in movie credits before. That is weird. At least I am not colour blind in that aspect! I had no idea about MARV studios and I never watched the movie; I thought at first it was short for Marvel!

Comment: Now that I know what to look for there is some additional information at [Marv Films - The Colorblind Test](http://www.closinglogos.com/page/Marv+Films).

Comment: Matthew Vaughn is colour blind, hence his use of a pseudoisochromatic plate for his new 'MARV; logo (it was first used in 'Kingsman: The Secret Service'). I do not know why this question has been closed as opinion based as Vaughn has been open about this for a while (including discussion os his excessive use of orange in 'Kick - Ass' - being a colour he thought he could 'see' more clearly as opposed to others.)